# Не видит метод openCV cvQueryHistValue_1D

Tags: c++, opencv

openCV 3.3.1
где подключить, чтобы виделась функция или есть замены?

```
float histValue = cvQueryHistValue_1D(hist, i);
```

Answer (score 1):

Как написано [здесь](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1238183) `cvQueryHistValue_1D` – одна из устаревших и удаленных функций. Заменить ее можно на `cvGetReal1D`. Также можно использовать [заголовочный файл compat.hpp](https://docs.opencv.org/ref/2.4/dc/da9/compat_8hpp.html#a860023682c0b2f8e115163960095b654), который заменяет устаревшие функции на новые. [Исходники можно взять отсюда](https://github.com/MasteringOpenCV/code/blob/master/Chapter2_iPhoneAR/Example_MarkerBasedAR/opencv2.framework/Versions/A/Headers/legacy/compat.hpp).